# Is there a way to make VIM open folds recursively when using "j" or "k"?

Tags: vim, folding

VIM conveniently opens a fold when you use `j` or `k` with your cursor inside it. It uses a shallow open, though - that is, `zo` - instead of a recursive open, or `zO`. Is there a way to make VIM use the recursive open when using `j` or `k`?

Answer (score 2):

There's no setting for that; Vim only opens the minimal set of folds so that the current line is unfolded.

But you can achieve that effect by overriding the commands:

```
:nnoremap j jzO
:nnoremap k kzO
```